# Is it possible to build a neural network without a target?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks

I have a dataset that describes the performances of a car depending on three parameters. Let me call for simplicity the three parameters $A$, $B$ and $Z$, and a performance index $l$, which the lower the better. Each entry is made of a value for $A$, $B$, $Z$ and $l$.
I would like to build a neural network that takes as inputs $A$, $B$ and outputs the best $Z$, i.e. the one that would have the lowest $l$.
I thought that I could use $l$ as a loss function but I do not have a target $\hat{Z}$ and I do not kown how to proceed.
Is it possible to build a neural network like this, or the only way is to compute $\hat{Z}$ in a separate way?
I would appreciate also suggestions that make use of other machine learning techniques to compute $Z$ or $\hat{Z}$, thank you.

Comment: This is closely related to response surface methodology

Comment: So you don't know what is "best" but would like NN to know that? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, your title is not quite right.

I assume you have a data set which has A, B, Z and I in it, so you can build a neural net to predict I from A, B, and Z.  I is your target

So, once you have this model, you could make up a data set of 100 cases with A always being the same, B always being the same, and Z varying 100 different ways. This can tell you the Z that gives the best I for a given A and B.

If Z is really more than one variable, then use a grid search.

As @JTH notes, this is related to response surface, but that's much too long to explain here, and doesn't use a neural net (in my experience).

Comment: I had the wrong point of view, this should solve my problem, thank you